# How to make the first row of a xamDataGrid have a different background color?

Tags: wpf, xamdatagrid

I want to make the first row of a xamDataGrid a different color because it holds a different type of data than the rest of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to put null checks etc, just a few statements to to keep it concise..

```
var red = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
var item = dataGrid.Items[0];//or First(), FirstOrDefault()
var row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as GridViewRow;

row.Background = red;
```

or add a property to you class IsFirstRow and do something like below:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}"> 
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/> 
    <Style.Triggers> 
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirstRow}" Value="True"> 
            <DataTrigger.Setters> 
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
            </DataTrigger.Setters> 
        </DataTrigger> 
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there a way to accomplish this in the xaml instead?